# jquery autocomplete gem fails with mysql2 error in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

Using:

jquery3-autocomplete gem at 1.0.5

jquery-rails gem at 1.0.19

mysql2 gem at 0.2.7

The autocomplete gem works as expected in jquery but I receive a mysql2 error:

```
  Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT jobs.id, jobs.title FROM `jobs` WHERE (LOWER(jobs.title) ILIKE 'te%') ORDER BY jobs.title ASC LIMIT 10
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ILIKE 'te%') ORDER BY jobs.title ASC LIMIT 10' at line 1: SELECT  jobs.id, jobs.title FROM `jobs` WHERE (LOWER(jobs.title) ILIKE 'te%') ORDER BY jobs.title ASC LIMIT 10
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 131ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ILIKE 'te%') ORDER BY jobs.title ASC LIMIT 10' at line 1: SELECT  jobs.id, jobs.title FROM `jobs` WHERE (LOWER(jobs.title) ILIKE 'te%') ORDER BY jobs.title ASC LIMIT 10):


# gemfile 
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

# jobs_controller.rb
  autocomplete :tag, :name
  autocomplete :job, :title

# routes.rb
  resources :jobs do 
    get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection    
    get :autocomplete_job_title, :on => :collection    
  end

#chrome console
GET http://localhost:3000/jobs/autocomplete_job_title?term=te 500 (Internal Server Error)
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajaxjquery.min.js:4
f.each.f.(anonymous function)jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.getJSONjquery.min.js:4
a.railsAutocomplete.fn.extend.init.a.autocomplete.sourceautocomplete-rails.js:16
d.widget._searchjquery-ui.min.js:326
d.widget.searchjquery-ui.min.js:326
(anonymous function)
```

Anyone have any ideas? I'm a little stumped on this one. It WAS working before and broke recently. Most likely because of a `bundle update` I ran, but I can't backtrace what the culprit was or confirm that it's actually the issue.

EDIT: FIXED ISSUE: 
I'm using Heroku so I had the PostgreSQL gem loading in my dev environment by accident. The dev environment uses mysql. This solved my problem - I hope it helps someone else.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Heroku so I had the PostgreSQL gem loading in my dev environment by accident. The dev environment uses mysql. This solved my problem - I hope it helps someone else.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```